# Neo4J nodes aggregation

Tags: neo4j

Is there a concept of (advanced) nodes aggregation in Neo4J?

I mean something like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) for elasticsearch.

Comment: I know that are two very different databases, but If I am asking the wrong question please explain me why. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really see what you want to do ... what kind of aggregation you want to make ? You can do a lot of aggregations in Cypher and since version 3.2 you can create your own aggregation function.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Can you share some documentation?

Comment: Seconding logisima, please add an example of a Cypher query and what kind of results you want from it.

Answer (score 0):

The build in neo4j aggregate functions can be found [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/)

But I expect you want custom aggregation functions.  You'll have to write the functions in java.  I think the documentation is pretty clear, and should be found [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/#user-defined-aggregation-functions).